# convert this code from c++ to C#

Tags: c#, rsa, converters, encryption

i cant convert d->max to C# i use openssl and the problem of convert c++ to C# the bignum of Rsa->d i cant found it in Openssl Reference in C# rsa.d not found

```
rsa->n
rsa->e
```

Comment: sorry, what's the question exactly?

Comment: i dont understand c++ and i want convert n->dmax from c++ to C#

Comment: sorry ahmed, i voted to close because you haven't provided enough information here. go back, gather more information, and post a more thought-out question, so that we can help you out, bud - cheers.

Answer (score 3):

If we limit ourselves purely to the code in the question, then `->` is the pointer-to-member operator. In C# for both values and references that is `.`, so the equivalent code is just `rsa.n`, `rsa.e` and `d.max`. Unless it is an unsafe pointer to a struct, in which case `rsa->n`, `rsa->e` and `d->max` (so: the exact same code, but this is **very** unlikely in most C#).

However, I do **not** expect that will help you - I think you need to step back a few steps and look at *what you are trying to do*, rather than blindly trying to convert a sample you don't understand. It may well be that the *actual* solution here is to use a different library.

Comment: i use this reference openssl the link is http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net/  but the problem there is not e.dmax in this reference

Comment: @ahmed1041 and yet `e.dmax` doesn't even appear in the question. So again: what is the actual question here? When you know that, click "edit" to reflect that in the question you have asked.

Comment: my question how i can appear **e.dmax** in  the reference

Comment: @ahmed1041 saying the same thing repeatedly doesn't make it any clearer; basically, this question has nothing to do with converting any particular code to/from any languages, and everything to do with "how do I use a particular library". The answer to *that* is "read the documentation for that library". And if it still doesn't make any sense "choose a different library". You haven't given any indication of **what you are trying to do**. What you want to do is **not** "read `e.dmax`" - that is *how* you are trying to do it.

Comment: @ahmed1041 I've glanced at the library - is it possible  you want `.Size` ?